If $\dim(V_1)+\dim(V_2)=\dim(V),$ is it true that there is some $T:V\to V$ with $\ker(T)=V_1$ and $\Im(T)=V_2?$

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over a field $F.$ Let $V_1$ and $V_2$ be subspaces of $V$ with $\dim(V_1)+\dim(V_2)=\dim(V).$ Then, is it true that there is some linear transformation $T:V\to V$ with $\ker(T)=V_1$ and $\Im(T)=V_2?$

The motivation behind asking this question is the rank-nullity theorem:
For any linear transformation $T:V\to W,$ where $V$ and $W$ are vector spaces over the same field $F,$ we have $\dim(\ker(T))+\dim(\Im(T))=\dim(V).$
The above statement is obviously true when one of $V_1$ or $V_2$ is $V$ itself. In that case, we may take $T$ to be the identity on $V.$
I have also been able to construct linear transformations in other examples. For example, $\mathbb{Y}=\{(0,y):y\in\mathbb{R}\},$ and $\mathbb{X}=\{(x,0):x\in\mathbb{R}\}$ are both one-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^2.$ (I am taking the base field to be $\mathbb{R}$ in this example). Now, take $T:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ given by $T((x,y))=(x,0).$ Then, $\ker(T)=\mathbb{Y}$ and $\Im(T)=\mathbb{X}.$
Can this be shown in general?

Yes. Pick a basis for $V$ which begins with a basis for $V_1$ and ends with a basis for $V_2$. Do you see how to define $T$ on this basis so it has the properties you want?

@Malady, I'm guessing we set $T(v)=0$ if $v$ is in the basis for $V_1$ and $T(v)=v$ if $v$ is in the basis for $V_2.$ What to do about the elements that are in both the bases (if any)? And where did we use the fact that the dimensions sum up to $\dim(V)?$

We used that the dimensions sum to the dimension of $V$ to show that these bases do not intersect. See if you can show that.

Yes there is. Choose a basis $v_1,...,v_k$ for $V_1$ and extend it to a basis $v_1,...,v_k,...,v_n$ for $V$. Given the dimension assumption, $\dim (V_2)=n-k$. Let $w_1,...,w_{n-k}$ be a basis for $V_2$. In this basis, let the matrix for $T$ be $0$ in the first $k$ columns (corresponding to $V_1$) and let the remaining columns be the $w_i$s.
It is clear that $V_1$ is in the kernel since the first $k $ columns are zero. Since the remaining columns are independent, this is the whole kernel. Moreover, the image is given by the span of all columns, which is just $V_2$ as $w_1,...,w_{n-k}$ is a basis for $V_2$.

It's quick to show this fact when we have a direct sum between $V_1$ and $V_2$, When $\text{dim}(V_1\cap V_2) = r>0$ you can map $r$ vectors in the intersection in the null vector. From the base extension you get $r$ more vectors mapped in a basis of the intersection
